# count occurrences of word in json file python

Tags: python, json

I am working on a program that needs to be able to count the amount of time a word (like parsed_text) is mentioned in a JSONa file. So far I have come up with some code that I think could work but it never gets the amount a word is used correctly. This is my Code:

```
with open("Adlogica logo picker-ATrecords.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    ATdata = json.load(f)
    total = sum(1 for line in f.readlines() if 'parsed_text' in line)
    print(total)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: zr0gravity7's answer is correct that `json.load(f)` is not necessary, though it is worth noting for you that `json.load` does absorb all the contents from the `.json` file, so there is nothing left to read in the file when `f.realines()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that I found more elegant than looping.

```
search_word = 'parsed_text'
with open("some_file.json", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    total = data.count(search_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) from the `re` (RegEx) module to find all occurrences of the search word (where it is surrounded by [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)).

```
import re

with open("Adlogica logo picker-ATrecords.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    # ATdata = json.load(f) # not necessary

    searchWord = 'parsed_text'

    total = 0
    for line in f:
        total += len(re.findall(f"\b{searchWord}\b", line))

    print(total)
```

Comment: This is I think what I need but don't you need to define total first? That is an error I am getting

Comment: My mistake, I had added it but I must have discarded the edit. Fixed now.